# Resolving Value Error: Decision Tree Regressor

Tags: python, decision-tree

I'm getting a value error on my python code, because part of the data has a string and float. Im using Kaggle Imdb data, which has both floats and strings. I need help with changing the code so the string is allowed.

Not sure how to change the string to float in order to resolve the error.

```
enter code here
```

f

```
rom sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

#setting the imdb features import in the data

imdb_features=['original_title','genre','director','actors','avg_vote','reviews_from_users','reviews_from_critics']
X= imdb_moviedata[imdb_features]

#Building Model

imdb_moviedata_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)

#Fit the model

imdb_moviedata_model.fit(X,y)
```

Receiving the following Error code:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------`enter code here`
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-61e73a0f75b7> in <module>
      3 imdb_moviedata_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
      4 #Fit the model
----> 5 float(imdb_moviedata_model.fit(X,y))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
   1240         """
   1241 
-> 1242         super().fit(
   1243             X, y,
   1244             sample_weight=sample_weight,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    154             check_X_params = dict(dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    155             check_y_params = dict(ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
--> 156             X, y = self._validate_data(X, y,
    157                                        validate_separately=(check_X_params,
    158                                                             check_y_params))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    427                 # :(
    428                 check_X_params, check_y_params = validate_separately
--> 429                 X = check_array(X, **check_X_params)
    430                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    431             else:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    596                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    597                 else:
--> 598                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    599             except ComplexWarning:
    600                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   1779 
   1780     def __array__(self, dtype=None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 1781         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   1782 
   1783     def __array_wrap__(self, result, context=None):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Miss Jerry'
```

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-61e73a0f75b7> in <module>
      3 imdb_moviedata_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
      4 #Fit the model
----> 5 imdb_moviedata_model.fit(X,y)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
   1240         """
   1241 
-> 1242         super().fit(
 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Miss Jerry'